# How to select an optimal number of clusters in my example?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I want to group my dataset using clustering technique. I apply k-means and used Dunn index and  Silhouette Coefficient for the validation (selection of the best number of clusters). Now I want to know what should be the optimal cluster number based on the Dunn index. For your reference i am uploading the DI and SC plot ("cluster size" is the number of clusters).

The point is that if I keep on increasing the cluster no's the DI value is getting higher after 7. The minimum value in figure is 5. So can't we take 5 as the min no of cluster possible.

Please suggest what should be the cluster size i need to consider for this plot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I reckon to go with 7 clusters? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunn_index#Explanation

Comment: `cluster size` What's that? Are you speaking about the number of clusters?

Comment: Yes. I want to find the optimal no of clusters.

Comment: There exist plenty, plenty internal clustering criterions (validation criterions). Each one has its "preferences" or "biases". Dunn's index and Silhouette index are just two of the many. By the way, both these two exist in original as well as in modified versions. The two are quite different conceptually and don't have to be concordant most of the time. In your example, Dunn suggests the 7 clusters and Silhouette - the 2 clusters. If you want a forced negotiation solution you might take the 3-cluster solution as not bad.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes such as Dunn's and Silhouette only are a **heuristic**. Even if they *would* agree on a single k, you **never rely on them** anyway. Because they will sometimes not work.

In particular, when the data is not well preprocessed, or the clusters do not match the k-means assumptions, then the indexes will not work either.

It's okay to use the indexes to find the first k to *try*, though. But I strongly recommend to always 1. visualize the clusters. 2. carefully study the resulting clusters, don't just assume they are good.

Comment: `But I strongly recommend to always 1. visualize the clusters. 2. carefully study the resulting clusters, don't just assume they are good.` So do I. Mind, _however_, that eye is just one among "clustering criterions" with its own [prejudices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia), so visualization, even if easily possible, isn't the _ultimate judge_. Some reasonable good and interpretable cluster solutions may be perceived by eye as inconvincing.